# Store json data into database for reduce internet charges

Tags: android, json, android-json, android-webservice

I have developed an application that can fetch data(Images and Text) from server using json parsing so my question is i am trying to implement like one time data download and store some where in my device and when I am run again application it fetch data from device not from web services so any one can sort out this problem right now i am using sqLite database for storing data

Comment: What is your problem then? i have work out this thing.

Comment: is there any solution because i want to store image

Comment: I have to store all the images into one `.Zip` file in my server and when i login first time fetch this `.Zip` file in `InputStream` and Extract into my Private Directory and also add `data(ImagePath)` into `SQLite` Table. this all case is for first time Login only. now, when internet not available load all the data from `SQLite` and when internet available ask to user if he/she want to update app data. if he/she want then download new `data (Sync)` with older `SQLite` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `SQLite` DB (it's very simple, you can start reading from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db or here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and add a timestamp to the data you've fetched from the Web. Then once you start your app if data in DB is quite old (calculate the difference between timestamp and current time), then just pull the new data.